# Составить SQL запрос UPDATE

Tags: sql, select, update

Таблица:

```
 contentid   tmplvarid    value

     475         21        3000
     475         37         _    (тут 0)

     476         21        3500
     476         37         _    (тут 1)

     477         21        3000
     477         37         _    (тут 0)
```

contentid - товар, 21 - его масса, 37 - код массы. Надо каждому товару вместо _ поставить код 0 если масса 3000, (и 1 если 3500 - это уже вторым запросом)

Типа того, но я совсем не понимаю в этом, пытаюсь учиться.

```
UPDATE `table` SET `value`='0'  WHERE tmplvarid=37 
         AND (SELECT `value` FROM `table` WHERE value = 3000 AND tmplvarid=21)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE `table` SET `value`=0  
WHERE 
  tmplvarid = 37 AND 
  contentid in (SELECT contentid FROM `table` WHERE value = 3000 AND tmplvarid=21)
```